# How to get a per file size report from a git bare repository?

Tags: git, git-bare

I would like to get a report of size per file from a group of git repositories. I was trying the below command by referring to a blog and which doesn't give me the actual size, Could someone suggest a git command that can be run on the bare repository.

```
for i in `git rev-list --all`; do git ls-tree -r --long $i; done
100644 blob 8bb811be17d13c6f2f8a4c3a71436f8c4ba1cac2      84    src1/.gitattributes
100644 blob e54bba69963bebd4be9ace5db0e2b6efbe405e8b     126    src1/1.txt
100644 blob 69670a2a3ac9098eb1789aa4b63d8efc67ec0ab8     127    src1/2.txt
100644 blob 661d46743ad7edc60f5904e5d732d536991969d0     132    src1/prp-1.4.2.jar
100644 blob 6a6ccf5d874fec134ee712572cc03a0f2dd7afec      42    src1/.gitattributes
100644 blob e54bba69963bebd4be9ace5db0e2b6efbe405e8b     126    src1/1.txt
100644 blob 69670a2a3ac9098eb1789aa4b63d8efc67ec0ab8     127    src1/2.txt
100644 blob 357dde1f346c96c32e8e4ca26ebce5d0a84ad5ab       9    src1/1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The 4th column in `git ls-tree -r --long` is the actual size. For example, in

```
100644 blob 8bb811be17d13c6f2f8a4c3a71436f8c4ba1cac2 84 src1/.gitattributes
```

**84** is the size.